# Webform_SaveScrollPositionSubmit is not defined

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Cut a short story even shorter, Have a asp.net page with  MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" in the page directive (And I tried setting the same to true in page_load), but I get the above javascript error (Webform_SaveScrollPositionSubmit is not defined) and im guessing the page dosent scroll because that js function is "not defined"...

Using asp.net 2.0 and firefox 3...dosent work in internut exploader too. Have tried running aspnet_regiis -c, but no joy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind! It seems a custom HttpModule (that has a ResponseFilter) is doing some nasty things to the page. Going to rewrite the HttpModule as a HttpHandler and bind it to *.aspx so it doesnt interfere with WebResource.axd

Comment: Hey there, if you're still around, mind editing to expand on this further? It would be helpful for people to hear how you managed to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I had a custom HttpModule that was intercepting all calls - one of which was the WebResource.axd, whcih webforms uses to load up JS for stuff like the scroll position - mess around with the JS that the .axd file pumps out, and it no longer works.